# How to process a file like each line is a command with argparse or similar

Tags: python, argparse

I am creating a program that reads a list of files from some text file and then does various things with them. I want to be able to read each line and then process it like it was typed in in a CLI. For example:

```
~/test1.txt -r
~/test2.txt -w "hello"
```

Where the flag `-r` saves the text in the file to some object and `-w` appends whatever string argument follows that flag to the file. In this case would append "hello" to `test2.txt`.

I know of argparse, and it does exactly what I want, but it only reads and processes commands from the command line. Is there a way to parse strings that I already have in my program like I described above?

If it cant be done with argparse, are there any other decent solutions other then coding it myself?

Comment: You're going to have to do some coding

Comment: Combine `shlex.split` and `ArgumentParser.parse_args` (with  `args` argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is your want to read from a text file and treat each line as command line arguments. Here is what get you started.

```py
import argparse
import pathlib
import shlex

# Create a parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-r", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-w")
parser.add_argument("filename")

# Read the lines from the text file
data_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("input.txt")
with open(data_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as stream:
    for line in stream:
        print(f"\n# {line.strip()}")
        tokens = shlex.split(line)
        options = parser.parse_args(tokens)
        print(options)

        # Do something with options
```

Output:

```
# ~/test1.txt -r
Namespace(r=True, w=None, filename='~/test1.txt')

# ~/test2.txt -w "hello"
Namespace(r=False, w='hello', filename='~/test2.txt')
```

#### Notes

Normally, we call `parse.parse_args()`, which parses the command-line arguments.

In order to parse a text line, we need to split that line and pass the list of tokens into `parse_args`.

Do not use `line.split()`: it does not understand quotes and escaped characters. Instead, we use `shlex.split()` which take care of those details.

#### Update

Thank you to Charles Duffy for pointing out the ~ expansion. That can be easily fixed with the following changes:

```py
import os
...

parser.add_argument("filename", type=os.path.expanduser)
```

Comment: Thank you, @CharlesDuffy. I have updated my post.